# How to pickle a Sklearn pipeline with text and non-text features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I already browsed all the similar questions I found in StackOverflow and unfortunately none of them did it for me.

I have a Pipeline that is combining unions and using function transformers

```
get_text_data= FunctionTransformer(return_text, validate=False)

get_categorical_data= FunctionTransformer(func=return_categorical, kw_args=dict(columns=categoricalFeatures), validate=False)


vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii',tokenizer=tokenize, min_df=2,stop_words ='english',ngram_range=(1, 2))#

clf=svm.SVC(kernel='linear',cache_size=10000, C=1.3)#86.6 with extra text =(

# Instantiate Pipeline object: pl
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('union', FeatureUnion(
            transformer_list = [
                ('discrete_features', 
                    Pipeline([
                    ('selector', get_categorical_data) ])),

                ('text_features', 
                    Pipeline([
                    ('selector', get_text_data),
                    ('vectorizer', vectorizer)]))

                                ]
        )),
        ('clf', clf)
    ])
pipeline.fit(x,y)
pickleModel(pipeline,'pl_4_2_2018_TS_caseType')
```

By the way, if I don't alias dill as pickle, I get an error saying "I can't pickle lambda objects"

After this is pickled, i call the same pipeline and feed it new data

```
pl = loadModel(pipeline_name)
all_nonDUDLpredictions=pl.predict(x)
```

This fails however telling me that

```
in _convert_t_indexer
raise KeyError ('% is not in index' % objarr[mask]')
KeyError: [List of all the categorical features] not in Index
```

I can run the pipeline when I train it and get an accuracy so that seems to work but for some reason I can't feed it new data if I pickle it

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `joblib.dump`?

Comment: Yes, if I use that then I get the "can't pickle lambda functions" =/

Comment: There are fixes for that. The `dill` library helps pickle lambdas. Alternatively, don't use a lambda? Use a named function instead.

Comment: You mean instead of this (lambda x: x[categoricalFeatures], validate=False) use just a regular function?

Comment: Yup, create a function `f` and pass it

Comment: Modified with function an now I can pickle with joblib but upon loading it (with joblib again) it gives me the same error. It is the categorical features that it doesn't like: File: Anaconda\envs\snakes3.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py.  line 1229 in _convert_to_indexer raise KeyError(%s not in index % objarr[mask]) [list of categorical features]

Comment: Are you unpickling with a different version? That's usually the cause in these instances.

Comment: Using same version, I just did an experiment. It seems that it is complaining that "i see these categories in the test set that were not in the training set therefore I am crashing". If if feed the unpickled model with the same data (except the Y variable) then it works but as soon as it sees data with different categorical features it complains... no clue why its doing that

Comment: All right, I think I may have found what's going on. The categorical features can change after the model is pickled. Say for example during training 10 features in the categorical pipeline were trained but the test set can have those 10 plus or minus other features. So I have 2 options: first is to treat this as text and use vectorizer or get a list of categorical features in the training set and filter the test set by those